Some guidance needed ,Spivak Problem 7-18(c)

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $x$ be any
number. Prove that there is a point on the graph of $f$ which is
closest to $(x,0)$; in other words there is some $y$ in  $\mathbb{R}$
such that the distance from $(x,0)$ to $(y,f(y))$ is $\le$ the
distance from  $(x,0)$ to  $(z,f(z))$ for all $z$ in $\mathbb{R}$

So we must prove there is a number $y$ such that $$\sqrt{(x-y)^2+(f(y))^2}\le \sqrt{(x-z)^2+(f(z))^2}$$
for all $z$ in $\mathbb{R}$
we can define a new function $d$, where by $d(z)=\sqrt{(x-z)^2+(f(z))^2}$. (Note that $d$ is continuous)
At this point in the exercise this theorem has been proven for closed intervals. My idea was to construct a sufficiently large closed interval such that the minimum on the interval is the global minimum. So, for any $b>0$ on the interval $[-b+x,b+x]$ there exist a $y$ in  $[-b+x,b+x]$ such that $d(y)\le d(z)$ for every $z$ in  $[-b+x,b+x]$. Now all we have to do is choose a large enough $b$ such that $$|x-b|\ge d(y)$$
by doing this you essentially guarantee that for any number $\alpha$ not in  $[-b+x,b+x]$,$d(\alpha) $ must necessarily be $d(\alpha)\gt d(y)$ because $d(\alpha)>|x-b|$ . I took a look at the answer book and Spivak takes advantage of the fact that $d(z)\ge|x-z$| and solves it a manner analogous to a past problem in typical Spivak fashion. However, I am more interested in my proof and whether I have the right idea, thanks.

You correctly argue that for any $b>0$ there exists $y_b \in [-b+x,b+x]$ such that $d(y_b)\le d(z)$ for every $z \in [-b+x,b+x]$. However, you cannot be sure that you can take the same $y$ for all $b$ - the point $y_b$ in general depends on $b$.

Now all we have to do is choose a large enough $b$ such that $|x-b|\ge d(y_b)$.

You do not explain how this can done (note that $b$ occurs on both sides of the inequality). Thus you have a gap.
Here is a suggestion.
The case $f(x) = 0$ is trivial; simply take $y = x$.
If $f(x) \ne 0$, let $b = \lvert f(x)  \rvert$. There is $y_b \in [-b+x,b+x]$ such that $d(y_b) \le d(z)$ for all $z \in [-b+x,b+x]$. In particular  $d(y_b) \le d(x) = b$. For $z \notin [-b+x,b+x]$ we have
$$d(z) = \sqrt{(z-x)^2 + f(z)^2} \ge \lvert z - x \rvert \ge b = d(x)$$
which proves the theorem.

I think the cases should be $f(x) = 0$ (where $y = x$ works) and $f(x) \neq 0$ (then we let $b = |f(x)|$). Also the trivial case seems unnecessary since the next part works there too. If anyone is not comfortable with one-point intervals, just take $b = |f(x)| + 1$ instead.

@Adayah Thank you for pointing out the error

Let $d_{x_0}(x)=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(f(x)-f(x_0))^2}$ and $I_n=[x_0-n,x_0+n]$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. By continutity of $f$ and each $I_n$ being compact,
$$d_n=\min_{x\in I_n}d_{x_0}(x),\quad x_n=\underset{x\in I_n}{\mathrm{argmin}}\ d_{x_0}(x)$$
exist for all $n$. By $I_n\subseteq I_{n+1}$, $d_n$ is monotone decreasing, therefore bounded. Since $|x_n-x_0|\leq d_n$, $|x_n-x_0|$ is also bounded: for all $n$, $|x_n-x_0|\leq m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. But this means that $I_m$ contains the global minimizer.
